# Estimation of the standard error of intercept of the linnear regression using the delta method in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, intercept

I tried to estimate SE of the transformed intercept (10^a) from the linear regression using the delta method via "deltaMethod" function in the "car" package. But deltaMethod always gives zero for SE of the intercept or any of its transformations! For example, for untransformed intercept:

```
> x <- 1:100; y <- rnorm(100, 4*x, 5)
> m1<-lm(y~x) 
> library(car)
> deltaMethod(m1, "Intercept")
          Estimate      SE   2.5 %  97.5 %
Intercept  -1.9561  0.0000 -1.9561 -1.9561
```

According to "deltaMethod" function, intercept is 0.000, but it should be 0.9034276:

```
> (summary(m1))$ coefficients [1,2]
[1] 0.9034276
```

Function "deltamethod" from "msm" package gives right value of the intercept SE:

```
> library(msm)
> deltamethod (~ x1, coef(m1), vcov(m1))
[1] 0.9034276
```

But what is wrong with my code for "deltaMethod" function in the "car" package? (For some reason I prefer to use the "car" package than the "msm"). Thank you!

Comment: This works for me (I never get 0). Have you tried after restarting R ?

Comment: Just to let you know that I also encountered the same problem. I haven't been able to track down an answer as to the source of the problem. I actually was interested originally in evaluating the standard error for 1/(Intercept), but deltaMethod reported a zero standard error, and then I tried to obtain the standard error for (Intercept) and also got a zero standard error.
So I obtained the standard error for 1/(Intercept) with the deltamethod from the msm package, and also with an analytical solution, and both agreed and of course were different from zero.
What worries me is that the other est

Answer (score 0):

I cannot seem to reproduce your issue. One way we can test this is by writing a function that repeatedly creates data, fits the model, and returns the SEs as you have done above. We can pass this to the `replicate` function and repeat the procedure many times. Here is one way to investigate using your code:

```
set.seed(42)

library(car)

delta_sim <- function(){
  x <- 1:100; y <- rnorm(100, 4*x, 5)
  m1<-lm(y~x) 
  a <- deltaMethod(m1, "Intercept")
  list(a)
}

out <- replicate(1000, delta_sim())

out <- do.call(rbind, out)

hist(out$SE)
```

Which will yield the following:

[image: histogram of SE not including 1]

It might be worth restarting your R session to ensure that you don't have any local variables that are sneaking into your functions.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems, that the problem is in my R or PC, not in the "car" package. Yes, I restarted the R. I even updated R and all my packages to the latest versions. Alas, the error remains: the "car" always shows the correct intercept (or its transformations), but always gives SE=0 for it. Looks like I have to use "msm". By and large, this is not so important, but I'm just curious what kind of bug it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using code provided by MDEWITT produced all zeros on my machine. I tracked it down to the following part of `car::deltaMethod.default`

```
    para <- object         
    para.names <- names(para)
    para.names[1] <- gsub("\\(Intercept\\)", "Intercept", para.names[1])
    g. <- parse(text = g.)
    q <- length(para)

    envir <- new.env(parent=envir)
    for (i in 1:q) {
        assign(para.names[i], para[i], envir)
    }
    if(!missing(constants)){
     for (i in seq_along(constants)) assign(names(constants[i]), constants[[i]], envir)}
    est <- eval(g., envir)
    names(est) <- NULL
    gd <- rep(0, q)
    for (i in 1:q) {
        gd[i] <- eval(D(g., names(para)[i]), envir)
    }
```

Note the use of `names(para)[i]` in place of `para.names[i]`. The former has the parenthesis on the intercept, but the latter cleaned it out and probably should be used instead.  I was able to work around the problem by using the `parameterNames` argument of `deltaMethod` e.g.

```
    set.seed(42)
    
    library(car)
    
    delta_sim <- function(){
      x <- 1:100; y <- rnorm(100, 4*x, 5)
      m1<-lm(y~x) 
      a <- deltaMethod(m1, "b0", parameterNames=c("b0", "b1"))
      list(a)
    }
    
    out <- replicate(1000, delta_sim())
    
    out <- do.call(rbind, out)
    
    hist(out$SE)
```

Produced the desired output.